# csv.writer with a single quote character

Tags: python, special-characters, python-2.x

I have a row of data that I am trying to write to a .tab file that looks like this:

```
row = ['07/19/2017/10/33/30', 'gg_ca_18" dishwashers_204454792491_1t1',
       Decimal('369.00'), 1L, '66745355']
```

I want to leave the single quote not escaped so that it looks like this:

```
07/19/2017/10/33/30 gg_ca_18" dishwashers_204454792491_1t1  369.00  1   66745355
```

I am writing to a file using this code:

```
with open(file_name, 'wb') as outfile:
        a = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t') # ,escapechar=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE
        a.writerows(row)
```

I have tried using `escapechar=None, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE` and several variations of this. I always get the error `Error: need to escape, but no escapechar set`. What is the best way to not escape the single quote in the middle of the line? Is it possible using `csv` module?

Comment: What's wrong with escaping it?  Trying not to seems like a bad idea.

Comment: Is the opening parenthesis without a matching closing one intentional or is it a typo?

Comment: I don't want to escape the single quote because the system I am importing the data into doesn't recognize escaped characters.

Comment: @DYZ Are you talking about the open " in what I want as output? If so, that is intentional.

Comment: Someone already cleaned the typo for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just use a different `quotechar`:

```
with open(file_name, 'w') as outfile:
    a = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t', quotechar="'")
    a.writerow(row)
```

Comment: For Python 2 you should used `open(file_name, 'wb')` to open the file in binary mode.

Comment: I don't want to use any escape character.

Comment: @Hound You can also use `quotechar=None`, but the version I gave you will produce what you want for the example row you showed.

Comment: This works, but I don't quite understand why the single " gets wrapped with a " ""  (double quote)in the first place. 

If I use sysdout I don't see the problem, but if I open up the csv file I can see the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to escape anything, it is not a CSV file anymore. Convert each row item to a string, joint the strings into one string, and write it into the file:

```
line = ' '.join(map(str,row))
#'07/19/2017/10/33/30 gg_ca_18" dishwashers_204454792491_1t1 369.00 1 66745355'
outfile.write(line + "\n")
```

Answer (score -2):

If you want to escape a character, use `\`.

In you example, it would be `\"`